# How to add a unique identifier or number to a google.maps.Geocode request (Google Maps API v3)

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to be able to determine when the final request from my array of addresses has been processed so I can alert the user. Is there a way to determine when the request from the last address in an array has been processed? Can you attach an identifier to a request such that when it returns a call back function can see it and let the user know?

Otherwise the user is going to be sitting there waiting for markers that don't exist to appear. I've dealt with most of the issues arising from the asynchronous nature of the technology, but this one has me a little stumped and i haven't seen anything with the documentation.

Comment: Can't you just keep a count of the number of requests?

Comment: an unique identifier wouldn't help you much because there is no guarantee that you get the responses in the same order that you've sended the requests

Comment: Unfortunately you can't just count the requests because you can'y assume they finish in the same order and if you hit the query limit and re-submit then the number of requests would be larger than the array despite not completing. I think the answer lies in inserting a dummy point at the end and then testing for it.